# $\inf_{n}( \log(a_n))=\log (\inf_{n} (a_n))\;?$

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms, supremum-and-infimum

Let $(a_n)_n$ be a positive sequence.

> Why
>   $$\inf_{n}( \log(a_n))=\log (\inf_{n} (a_n))\;?$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** The $\log$ function is continuous and increasing.

Comment: I think that the  fact that log is increasing suffices to get  the  result.

Comment: But it is not. sufficient.

Comment: Could you please give me one other hint ? Thanks a lot. I don't understand where one use the continuity

Comment: For each $n$, $\inf_na_n\leqslant a_n$ and therefore (since $\log$ is increasing) $\log\left(\inf_na_n\right)\leqslant\log a_n$. Since this takes place for each $n$, $\log\left(\inf_na_n\right)\leqslant\inf_n(\log a_n)$. Now, suppose that $\log\left(\inf_na_n\right)<\inf_n(\log a_n)$. Take a subsequence of $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ whose limit is $\inf_na_n$. Use the fact that $\log$ is continuous (and, in particular, continuous at $\inf_na_n$) to get a contradiction.